# Room Database to set both NOCASE and RTRIM as collation for ColumnInfo

Tags: android, android-room

Can room database set multiple value as collate?

```
@Size(35)
@ColumnInfo(
  name = "SKU",
  typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.TEXT,
  collate = **{ColumnInfo.NOCASE, ColumnInfo.RTRIM}**
)
@RuntimeColumnInfo(name = "SKU")
public String sku;
```

If you what should be the syntax?

Comment: room is allowing following values for collate `UNSPECIFIED, BINARY, NOCASE, RTRIM, LOCALIZED or UNICODE.` but can you try to set two because from documentation it looks like you can use only one at a time.

Comment: Yes, it is quite common that the column should be case insensitive and right trim. Can't believe room database does not support it. Any alternative way to do it?

Comment: you can trim your values manually before you add or retireve them. basically trimming in getter and setter methods.

Comment: @KaranMer sure, but I try to achieve trim by room first...

Comment: not sure about that though, upvoting so somebody else might notice. better luck.